# idapython find functions that contain a loop

Tags: binary-analysis, idapython

How can I color functions that contain loops in IDApython ?

If the end of the basic block can jump to start of basic block it's good enough, even in the rare case this is not a loop. But how do i implement this ?

**EDIT**: This is not good cause the loop can span multiple basic blocks. 
Or, maybe if the `ecx` register is used ? I don't care if I have some false positives ?

Comment: Maybe searching for code xref where  frm > to  will find you already a narrow enough set of possible targets

Comment: You may find [this quesion](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/detecting-recursive-functions-in-ida/) useful. It is about finding recursive calls using IDA. Both answers are awesome.

Answer (score 7):

There is an IDA plugin called Loop Detection that does that, it comes with source code and a paper explaining how it works. Have a look at `loop_detection.cpp` and refer to the paper for an explanation of how it works.

Plugin with source code : http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/9/Loop_Detection
Paper: http://www.uninformed.org/?v=1&a=2&t=pdf

Looking for uses of `ecx` is not a good approach as this register is often used for other purposes. A better approach is to look for back edges between blocks.