# Is there anyway I can iterate all the C-level statements in IDA-Pro?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, ida-plugin, idapython, static-analysis

I am trying to iterate all the C `statement` (could be very coarse-grained, it's fine) in IDA-Pro recovered assembly program.

Suppose I only consider these statements:

```
State :: =
  | if-else cond;
  | loop;
  | assignment;
  | function call
  | return
  | {s1; s2; s3 ...}
```

And after some quick search, I know that there are some (third-party) plugins that can help to identify some `C` control-flow structure, and I list some of them below:

if-else cond  :   N/A

loop  : [link1](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6175/idapython-find-functions-that-contain-a-loop/6176#6176) [link2](https://hex-rays.com/contests/2011/index.shtml) [link3](http://old.idapalace.net/papers/loopdetection.pdf)

So my questions are:

1. Is there any plugins that can recover if/else statement? It looks easier than loop, but I just cannot find a well-developed way to recover the statement.
2. Is there anyway/api/scripts to iterate C statements in IDA-Pro? Or I have to implement myself?

Ideally it should look like this as this is essentially used in source code analysis... (sorry for this pseudo code, I just want to clarify)

```
let aux s =
    match s with
    | If e1 b1 b2 -> analyze e1 b1 b2
    | Loop e1 e2 e3 b1 -> analyze e1 e2 e3 b1
    | Assign v1 v2 -> analyze v1 v2 
    | States sl -> List.iter analyze sl
    | ...  in
List.iter aux statement_list
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there any plugins that can recover if/else statement? It looks easier than loop, but I just cannot find a well-developed way to
>      recover the statement.

Yes, the [Hex-Rays Decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) recovers if/else statements.

> 2. Is there anyway/api/scripts to iterate C statements in IDA-Pro? Or I have to implement myself?

Yes, the [Hex-Rays SDK](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/sdk.shtml) allows you to iterate the items (including if-else statements) in a decompilation tree.

Comment: A lot of functionality of HexRays SDK exists in IDAPython as a part of idaapi module in latest IDA versions (6.6 +).

Comment: @ws, would you mind to give an example here? thank you

Comment: The only thing I can give is a IDAPython samples at google code: https://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed   Desired code is in python files starting with vds