# What is the "standard" approach to find loop in binary code?

Tags: binary-analysis, binary

I am working on some x86 (32/64 bits) ELF binary code. These binaries are compiled from C and C++ program code and I am trying to detect loops inside the binaries.

I am newbie to this area, and I am wondering, what is the standard way to identify a loop in binary code?

I prefer to use some static methods to detect the loop instances, as I am not able to generate well-performing dynamic test cases.

Comment: Why do you think there's a standard way? Optimizations can make quite a mess...

Comment: @deviantfan, thank you. I agree with that. I am just wondering when people want to detect `loop`, what they will do? any references?

Comment: If you can get your hands on the book Practical Malware Analysis, I suggest you to read "Chapter 6. Recognizing C code constructs in assembly". There you have explained all the major code constructs of C language and how to identify them while reversing.

Comment: I am little bit surprise about unconstructive comments here. Optimizations can make mess, obviously, but they cannot hide structures of loops as well as recursive calls.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh If an optimization unrolls a loop so that it doesn't exist at all, there's no more loop to detect.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You are correct. I just mean that if loops exist in the binary code, then we have some methods to detect them. If they are not, then we cannot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic, compiler theoretic answer to this question is to build a control flow graph and then do a graph analysis to identify natural loops. I believe algorithms for this can be found in the [Dragon Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321486811), and a summary is given in these slides:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15745-s03/public/lectures/L7_handouts.pdf

You can also see how LLVM implements its loop detection:

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LoopInfo_8h_source.html

The search terms you want to find more information are things like "natural loop" and "back edge".

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/detecting-recursive-functions-in-ida) about finding recursive function helpful, there are very nice answers for it. Under the binary code level, IMHO, there is only little difference about detecting loop (i.e. some `jmp` to the same target) and recursive call (i.e. some `call` to the same target).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a standard way, but one approach might be to use something like [Johnson's algorithm](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0204007) to detect cycles in the function's directed graph.

You can find an implementation of this in libraries like [NetworkX simple_cycles](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html).

Answer (score 1):

Detecting loops from binary code isn't easily done. There are many algorithms based on multiple graph data structures (CFG, SSA form, DDG, ...).
I have provided a set of additional helpful documents [link1](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/502/notes/16-ssaopt.pdf), [link2](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs553/ClassNotes/lecture09-control-dominators.ppt.pdf), [link3](http://lenx.100871.net/papers/loop-SAS.pdf).
You can check [MAQAO](https://git.maqao.org/MAQAO/MAQAO/)'s implementation of an SSA based loop detector. Also, I would recommend you checking DynInst's code and documentation [link4](https://github.com/dyninst/dyninst/blob/master/parseAPI/src/LoopAnalyzer.h).

Now, you can implement an assembly code analyzer that can detect basic blocks/loops by following branches.

1. **Disassemble your binary and go thhrough instructions.**
2. **If a conditional jump is encountered (Jxx pattern), check whether it jumps above or below.**
3. **If the jump points above, check the distance (Delta(BRANCH_ADDRESS, BRANCH_TARGET_ADDRESS)), if the distance isn't too large (you'll have to decide of a limit) then you can apply some analysis on the branch condition (check whether it contains a register which is displaced [increment/decrement]). The branch condition analysis could be a simple pattern matching :**

   ```
      Example 1: 
                TEST X,X
                Jxx  X

      Example 2: 
                CMP  X,X
                Jxx  X

      Example 3: 
                DEC X
                Jnz X
   ```

If it all checks out, you got yourself a basic block which has a high probability of being a loop.

4. **If the jump points below, its probability of being part of a loop control structure is less likely. You can therefore ignore it and move on to the next instruction.**

If you need more hairy details, I'll be glad to provide more ;)

Comment: Thank you yaspr. I really appreciate your detailed information!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algo: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm)

You need to divide the assembler code into graphs (basic blocks) and find strongly connected graphs.
https://habr.com/ru/articles/331904/

https://habr.com/ru/articles/537290/